# Prove that an entanglement witness satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(W)>0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(W)^2\ge \operatorname{tr}(W^2)$

Tags: entanglement, entanglement-witness

If $W$ is an entanglement witness ($W \neq 0$), prove that

(a) $ tr(W) >0$

(b) $ tr(W)^2 > tr(W^2)$

For (a), by definition, since $ |ab\rangle$ is separable, thus $tr(\rho W)=\langle ab | W| ab \rangle \ge 0$. Then
$$
tr(W) = \sum_{i,j} \langle a_i b_j | W | a_i b_j \rangle \ge 0
$$
But I don't know how to prove it cannot be 0.

For (b), I have a hint: any state $\rho$ s.t. $tr(\rho^2)\le 1/(d-1)$, where $d$ is the dimension of $\rho$, is separable. But I have no idea how to use this property, and I also can't prove it.

Comment: for (a), you already wrote that the trace is a sum of expectation values over product states. If $W$ is a witness those are all non-negative, so the only way for the sum to be zero is that every single term is zero, which would imply $W=0$.

Comment: I don't think it is trivial that the diagonal terms are zero implying the whole $W$ is zero, I tried to prove this but failed.

Comment: is this an exercise from some textbook? also, I just realised in the title I put the inequality as $\operatorname{tr}(W)^2> \operatorname{tr}(W^2)$ rather than a strict inequality. However, I think that's how the statement should look like, considering as a counterexample the two-qubit swap operator, which is a witness, and has $\operatorname{tr}(W^2)=4=\operatorname{tr}(W)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), you've started well - taking a separable orthonormal basis and showing that the sum over all those expectations is non-negative. And, yes, you're right to worry that all those diagonal elements *could* be 0 given your starting point. So, let's assume they are all 0. But we're told that $W\neq 0$. So that would imply there's some off-diagonal element that's non-zero.

There are a couple of cases to deal with. Firstly, assume there's a non-zero element
$$
\langle a_1b|W|a_2b\rangle=re^{i\theta}.
$$
In this case, choose a new orthonormal basis that includes $|v\rangle=(|a_1\rangle+e^{-i\theta}|a_2\rangle)|b\rangle/\sqrt{2}$. Now we have $\langle v|W|v\rangle=r$ (don't forget that $W$ is Hermitian). So the diagonal elements cannot all be 0 unless $W=0$.

The other case is that there are no such choices of $a_1,a_2,b$. This must bean that there's a choice such that
$$
\langle a_1b_1|W|a_2b_2\rangle=re^{i\theta}.
$$
Now you can pick a new basis including the element
$$
|v\rangle=(|a_1\rangle+e^{-i\theta}|a_2\rangle)(|b_1\rangle+|b_2\rangle)/2.
$$
Again, evaluate $\langle v|W|v\rangle=r$. There are lots of cross terms which are 0 by assumption. The same conclusion holds.

I'm still thinking about the second part...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just cannot construct such $|v \rangle$ to find contradictions.

Answer (score 1):

(a) holds since $\mathrm{tr}(W)$ is the value the witness takes on the maximally mixed state. Since there is an open ball of separable states around the maximally mixed state, this implies that we can add $\varepsilon$ of any hermitian operator $H$ the maximally mixed state and $\mathrm{tr}((1\!\!1+\varepsilon H)W)$ is still non-negative. This is only possible if $\mathrm{tr}(W)$ is strictly positive. (To this this, you can e.g. choose $H=-W$.)

Comment: I think you are wrong, it is just like $tr(\rho^2)\le 1$, for Hermitian operators this still holds.

Comment: @Fireond My bad. I have instead now provided a simple answer to (a) ;)

Comment: It could be possible to prove (b) using a quantitative version of the above statement: There is a *specific* $\varepsilon$ s.th. $\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{tr}W1\!\!1/d -\varepsilon W)>0$; then, $(\mathrm{tr}(W)^2) > d\varepsilon \mathrm{tr}(W^2)$. If this still works for $d\varepsilon=1$, you are good.

Comment: to clarify: you're saying that $\operatorname{tr}((I+\epsilon H)W)=\operatorname{tr}(W)+\epsilon \operatorname{tr}(HW)$, and if $W\neq0$ one can choose $H$ to be a projection along a negative eigenvalue of $W$, thus $\operatorname{tr}((I+\epsilon H)W)<\operatorname{tr}(W)$, and thus you must have $\operatorname{tr}(W)=0$, lest there being entangled states arbitrarily close to the maximally mixed one?

Comment: @glS If you meant to say "must have $\mathrm{tr}(W)>0$", then yes. But $H=-W$ should also work. -- This can definitely be made quantitative as well and will give sth. along the lines of (b). Whether it actually gives (b) one would have to work out.